# Non-EU citizen, UK ILR, and Irish visa

Tags: uk, ireland, uk-residents, ukrainian-citizens, common-travel-area

I've got a non-EU passport and UK Indefinite Leave to Remain and I permanently reside in the UK. My country is on the list of the Irish Short-stay Visa Waiver Programme (which I don't understand if it's still suspended due to COVID or resumed if anyone knows?) and I can even travel visa-free to the Schengen area (which Ireland is not a part of).

I was planning to travel to Ireland to spend Christmas with my Irish friend, but even though there is the Common Travel Area, it appears I still need to apply for a visa? Is there any sort of a short-cut (legal, obviously) for the non-EU citizens and UK ILR holders to travel to Ireland? How long is the visa processing time? I just find this very frustrating, does anyone else have this experience?

Comment: The short-stay visa waiver for Ireland allowed people *visiting* the UK on short stay visas to travel to Ireland, while freedom of movement rights in the CTA apply only to Irish and British citizens. As you don’t have a UK short-stay visa you would not qualify even if the visa-waiver agreement (last renewed in 2016 until 31 Oct 21, IIRC) were not suspended. There’s no legal ‘short-cut’ for your situation unfortunately AFAIK https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/common-travel-area-guidance/common-travel-area-guidance

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is a bit odd & annoying that they allow visa-free travel with UK visit visas but not with permanent residency alright but not much that you can do about it.

The best place for info is probably the new [Irish immigration website](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/). They list visa processing times as ~8 weeks so you should be OK if you apply soon & are travelling at Christmas. May be quicker with less people travelling because of COVID, you never know.

Answer (score 2):

CTA only applies to British and Irish citizens. Even if you have a UK ILR or vice versa, you are still a citizen of a country you came from. If you are a national of a Visa required country to enter Ireland, you need to apply the Visa. Since you said you have ILR for UK and a national of a Visa required country then you need to apply the visa to enter Ireland. There's no short cut I'm afraid.